# How to call a Location method from a button click in Java Android?

Tags: java, android, button, methods, location

pretty new to java but after tutorials and such, I understand the basics. I'm trying to call a method I created to find the location of my device and then append the strings to a textview. How do I call this method from my button click? I tried just putting all the code inside my button so it would just run when clicked, but it doesn't like that. Does a button click have to contain a `View` parameter or because when I use `public onLocationChanged(Location location)` I get an error saying that it can't find the `public onLocationChanged(View)`. I tried doing `public onLocationChanged(View view, Location location)`but I get the same error in logcat. Thanks in advance for any help or feedback!

Edit: I saw on the android dev site "Now, when a user clicks the button, the Android system calls the activity's selfDestruct(View) method. In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter." when referring to the onClick parameter in the xml file. If I don't use this parameter and instead use the onClickListener method in the java file, can I use Location?

---

XML FILE

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/GPS"
    android:id="@+id/vid_message_button"
    android:onCLick="onLocationChanged" />
```

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

}



public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    if (view.getId() == R.id.send_GPS_button) {

    double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
    double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
    float accuracy = (float) (location.getAccuracy());
    double alt = (double) (location.getAltitude());
    double speed = (double) (location.getSpeed());
    double heading = (double) (location.getBearing());

    messageLogTextView.append("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(lat) + "\n" +
                    "Longitude: " + String.valueOf(longi) + "\n" +
                    "Accuracy: " + String.valueOf(accuracy) + "\n" +
                    "Altitude: " + String.valueOf(alt) + "\n" +
                    "Speed: " + String.valueOf(speed) + "\n" +
                    "Heading: " + String.valueOf(heading) + "\n");

    }    

}

public void onSendGPSButtonClick(View view) {

}
```

Comment: Yes, the view parameter is needed.

Comment: How can I get `location` in my button click or call the `onLocationchanged` method to perform the action then?

Comment: Pass just the view parameter, have an if condition to verify that this id is same as your button's id and then you could add the above code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have mentioned onLocationChanged for the android:onclick attribute of your Button's xml file, in your activity class, have the method with the signature onLocationChanged(View view).

Inside, this method, you can have

if (view.getId() == R.id.yourButtonName) {

//Add your above code for the location and setting the location to your textview

}

Comment: Can you take a look at my edit and tell me if that's what you were talking about? Thank you!